# Realize Node in geometry nodes causes some faces to Flip

Tags: geometry-nodes

**Realize Node** in geometry node **causes some faces to Flip**

When I try and add a realize instance node (need to do this since object will be exported to stl to 3D print).

Based off of question.
[Round / smooth the end points of curve in geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268252/round-smooth-the-end-points-of-curve-in-geometry-nodes)

**How can I prevent these faces from flipping when using the realize node?**

Some of the faces are flipped see animation.

[image: img1]

**Note: I tried doing the mesh to curve and curve to mesh trick but that didn't work.**

I also tried this suggestion [Recalculate normals of an object using geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276473/recalculate-normals-of-an-object-using-geometry-nodes)  (it flipped more faces)

Attached file below:

[image]

Comment: If you want a 3D print of this object, in the end, it will have to be manifold. Would an entirely different way of modelling it be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I'm always willing to learn something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are flipping because you're turning them inside out by scaling them to $-1$. If you use a `Rotate Instances` instead of `Scale Instances` to rotate them $180º$ , they'll stay as they are:

[image]

I admit I hadn't noticed the behaviour that instances don't reflect what should be the correct flip orientation until they're realized. I'm not sure if that's a bug, a natural technical outcome, a performance consideration, a design choice, or overlays system failing to pick up the change or something else, though.